# How to set permissions to public, Elastic Transcoder Amazon SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3

How I can make all files public using Amazon.ElasticTranscoder.Model (.NET, C#).
Here is my code:

```
public static void CreateJobRequest(string videoPath, string bucketName)
{
string accsessKey = CloudSettings.AccessKeyID;
string secretKey = CloudSettings.SecreteKey;
var etsClient = new AmazonElasticTranscoderClient(accsessKey,secretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
var notifications = new Notifications()
{
Completed = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:Transcode",
Error = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:Transcode",
Progressing = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:Transcode",
Warning = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:Transcode"
};

var pipeline=etsClient.CreatePipeline(new CreatePipelineRequest()
{
Name = "MyFolder",
InputBucket = bucketName,
OutputBucket = bucketName,
Notifications = notifications,
Role = "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/Elastic_Transcoder_Default_Role"

}).CreatePipelineResult.Pipeline;
etsClient.CreateJob(new CreateJobRequest()
{
PipelineId = pipeline.Id,
Input = new JobInput()
{
AspectRatio = "auto",
Container = "mp4",
FrameRate = "auto",
Interlaced = "auto",
Resolution = "auto",
Key = videoPath

},
Output = new CreateJobOutput()
{
ThumbnailPattern = videoPath+"videoName{resolution}_{count}",
Rotate = "0",
PresetId = "1351620000000-000020",
Key = videoPath+"newFileName.mp4"
}
});
}
```

Everything works perfect, but transcoded files are private. How I can set it to public?

Answer (score 20):

I've just had this issue today and the way to resolve it is as follows:

In your Pipeline under "Configure Amazon S3 Bucket for Transcoded Files and Playlists"

1. Use the "+ Add a permission link".
2. Select "Grantee Type" as "Amazon S3 Group".
3. Select "Grantee" as "All Users".
4. Then check "Access" as "Open/Download" AND "View Permission"
5. Save changes.

You can repeat this for any thumbnails that are generated in the section directly beneath: "Configure Amazon S3 Bucket for Thumbnails".

Comment: Thanks! May I ask why "View Permission" is required?

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to @timstermatic answer - I only had to grant 'Open/Download' access to make the objects public.

The 'View Permissions' option is used to allow anyone to read the [ACL (Access Control List)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ACLOverview.html) of the object, not to view the object itself - that's taken care of by the 'Open/Download' option.

As usual with AWS terms, it's easy to misinterpret - it's not 'Permission to View the Object', it's 'View the Object's Permissions'.

(Sorry I couldn't add this as a comment, I don't have enough rep.)

Comment: Sometimes I swear they're doing it on purpose just to mess with us.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a conflict in policies can give rise to this situation. An easier way to handle this is to set the public read permission straight on the bucket in the "Bucket Policy" section of the Permissions tab. This bit of code might help.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET_NAME>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can specify the folder as well in the Resource parameter. Haven't tried extensions but I guess those should work too.